# Error when sending email from localhost using php

Tags: php, email

I'm trying to send some email from localhost XAMPP to outlook mail but it only display "Error" message. My code is working properly in web server side.

I'm using 64 bit. I follow the instruction properly, how to set up sending email using XAMPP.

Sometimes the email sent but mostly it's not and always "connection timeout". Even if it display email "sent", i didn't receive any email.

How to fix this?

Here's the php.ini

```
 SMTP = smtp.live.com
 smtp_port = 587
 sendmail_from = same email as sendmail.ini
 sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
```

sendmail.ini

```
 smtp_server=smtp.live.com
 smtp_port=587
 auth_username=outlook email
 auth_password=********
 force_sender=outlook email
```

My email php

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

/* Email Detials */

$mail_to      = "email";
$from_mail    = "email";
$from_name    = "title";
$reply_to     = "";
$subject      = "subj...";
$message_body = "";

/* Attachment File 
Attachment location */

$file_name = "filename.xml";
$path = "C:/xampp/htdocs/Email/";

// Read the file content

$file      = $path . $file_name;
$file_size = filesize($file);
$handle    = fopen($file, "r");
$content   = fread($handle, $file_size);
fclose($handle);
$content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));

/* Set the email header 
Generate a boundary */

$boundary = md5(uniqid(time()));

// Email header

$header = "From: " . $from_mail . " \r\n";
$header .= "Reply-To: " . $reply_to . "\r\n";
$header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";

// Multipart wraps the Email Content and Attachment
$header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\r\n";
$header .= " boundary=\"" . $boundary . "\"";

$message_body .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n\r\n";
$message_body .= "--" . $boundary . "\r\n";

/* Email content
Content-type can be text/plain or text/html */

$message_body .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\r\n";
$message_body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n";
$message_body .= "\r\n";
$message_body .= "$message_body\r\n";
$message_body .= "--" . $boundary . "\r\n";

/* Attachment
Edit content type for different file extensions */

$message_body .= "Content-Type: application/xml;\r\n";
$message_body .= " name=\"" . $file_name . "\"\r\n";
$message_body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
$message_body .= "Content-Disposition: attachment;\r\n";
$message_body .= " filename=\"" . $file_name . "\"\r\n";
$message_body .= "\r\n" . $content . "\r\n";
$message_body .= "--" . $boundary . "--\r\n";

// Send email
if (mail($mail_to, $subject, $message_body, $header)) {
    echo "Sent";
} else {
    echo "Error";
}
```

Comment: Maybe that link can help u : http://www.mittalpatel.co.in/php_send_mail_from_localhost_using_gmail_smtp

Comment: Your `php.ini` should have `SMTP=smtp.live.com`, not `SMTP=smtp:live.com`.

Comment: @isim i change it now, but still i have an error

Answer (score 0):

Does your machine has access to port 587 ?. (you can try with telnet or putty). If the port is closed you should take a look at your firewall or your router.